# how to implement onItemClickListener for this coverflow app in android

Tags: android, onclick, abstract-class, coverflow, onitemclicklistener

I am having trouble getting the onItemClickListener to work in my code.  to test it i put a Toast inside the onClick to show some text on the screen if one of the views (images in the coverflow) is clicked,  but no result.  i am probably doing something wrong.  what should i do?

there are two parts of the code shown below.  the first part is from the coverFlowExample.java class file that i am using to implement the coverflow activity, the second part of code that is below is from the other class file called, abstract class CoverAdapterView, it has the abstract methods for the OnItemClickListener.

the below code is in the oncreate method of the coverflowactivity activity.

i had to make the "int = xu position" because the compiler would not let me directly use the int position variable that is part of the parameters taken in the onItemClick method

```
   // inner class inside of onCreate method for implememting OnIteimClickListener

        class ClickOnImage implements OnItemClickListener {  

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(CoverAdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            int xu = position;

            Toast.makeText(CoverFlowExample.this, "clicked on one of  the images " + xu, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

next is the code that has to do with the OnItemClickListener that is in the other class file

```
  public abstract class CoverAdapterView<T extends Adapter> extends ViewGroup {

  // inside this abstract class the below code is refers to the OnItemClickListener

  /**
  * The listener that receives notifications when an item is clicked.
  */
  OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

   /**
  * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an item in this
  * AdapterView has been clicked.
  */
   public interface OnItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
     * been clicked.
     * <p>
     * Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need
     * to access the data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param parent The AdapterView where the click happened.
     * @param view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this
     *            will be a view provided by the adapter)
     * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
     * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked.
     */
    void onItemClick(CoverAdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id);


    }

   /**
    * Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
    * been clicked.
    *
    * @param listener The callback that will be invoked.
    */
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = listener;
   }

   /**
    * @return The callback to be invoked with an item in this AdapterView has
    *         been clicked, or null id no callback has been set.
    */
    public final OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
    return mOnItemClickListener;
   }

   /**
   * Call the OnItemClickListener, if it is defined.
   *
   * @param view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked.
   * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
   * @param id The row id of the item that was clicked.
   * @return True if there was an assigned OnItemClickListener that was
   *         called, false otherwise is returned.
   */
    public boolean performItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
        playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(this, view, position, id);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting the OnItemClickListener on the view object that you are expecting the click on?

```
ListView mListView;

mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xml_layout_view_name);

mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickOnImage())
```

My first guess would be that your ClickOnImage class is not connected to the object being clicked on.

Comment: @collusionbdbh how can i apply animation only on selected item means if my selected position is 2 then only 2th item imageview should display animation while rest of the others remains same

Comment: Your onItemClick function has a parameter "int position". so something like:    if(position == 1) "show amination since the 1st item will be at postion 0 and the 2nd at position 1" add an else if there is a different animation for other items.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **setOnItemClickListener** method, Like...

```
    CoverFlow  coverFlow;
    coverFlow = new CoverFlow (this);  

    coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(CoverAdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

             System.out.println("----------------->"+ position );


        }

    });
```

Good luck.

Comment: but if i want to apply animation inside adapter class that extends from FancyCoverFlowAdapter  now appling animation in imageview click but animation is not applying while same animation is working in activity class on fancyCoverFlow object but not in adapter class inside item why ?